# Can someone help me with the column sorting code in perl

Tags: perl, sorting

I am learning perl and wanted to sort a column in a file. I found this code online.

```
my @array = ( 
   "kyy1         x753y420 31082010 07:01:11", 
   "exr1         x831y444 31082010 07:43:45", 
   "eef1         x717y532 31082010 07:30:17", 
   "bab3         x789y486 31082010 08:08:56", 
   "sam1        x1017y200 31082010 07:25:18", 
   "jmd2         x789y466 31082010 07:38:22", 
   "baa3cqc      x720y440 31082010 07:26:37"
);

# Sort by first column - login name
my @sortedName = sort { (split ' ', $a)[0] cmp (split ' ', $b)[0] } @array;

# Sort by second column - SKU number
my @sortedSkno = sort { (split ' ', $a)[1] cmp (split ' ', $b)[1] } @array;

# Sort by third - date - and fourth - time - column combined!
my @sortedTime = sort { (split ' ', $a)[2].(split ' ', $a)[3] cmp (split ' ', $b)[2].(split ' ', $b)[3] } @array;

print "Array\n";
print join( "\n", @array )."\n\n";

print "Sort Name\n";
print join( "\n", @sortedName )."\n\n";

print "Sort Skno\n";
print join( "\n", @sortedSkno )."\n\n";

print "Sort Date\n";
print join( "\n", @sortedTime )."\n\n";
```

But i don't understand the following line completely

```
# Sort by first column - login name
my @sortedName = sort { (split ' ', $a)[0] cmp (split ' ', $b)[0] } @array;
```

What i don't get is that, sort function takes two arguments `(split ' ', $a)[0]` and `(split ' ', $b)[0]`. These represent the special variables `$a` and `$b` used by sort function. If that is true then how come split function have `$a` again as in `(split ' ', $a)[0]` !?

Comment: `$a` and `$b` correspond to the elements in your array. You can read about it here: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html

Comment: `$a` and `$b` are indeed the special variables, but you can transform them in various ways--e.g. split them up and use a certain element in the resultant array to sort on.

Comment: ok. Two questions.1)When sort is used on a array with say (1,2,3) $a takes 1,$b takes 2? then when does 3 come into picture. 2)Can anyone explain me in brief whats happening conceptually when sort { (split ' ', $a)[0] cmp (split ' ', $b)[0] } @array is executed.

Comment: The sorting routine takes two elements from its list of arguments and compares them.  The `cmp` operator returns `1`, `0`, or `-1`, depending on whether the left hand operator is bigger, equal, or smaller than the right. E.g. `"a" cmp "b"` returns `-1`. This comparison is then used by the internal mergesort routine, which does the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

The following modification is understood much better. Its same as

```
my @sortedName=sort { (split ' ', $a)[0] cmp (split ' ', $b)[0] } @array
```

but much more readable. This is the modification

```
 my @sortedName=sort{ @arr_a=split(' ',$a);
        @arr_b=split(' ',$b);
        @arr_a[0] cmp @arr_b[0];
      }(@array);
```

Here the @array is read and two arguments or elements from the list are saved in $a and $b. These are then split using spaces and stored in @arr_a,@arr_b. Then we just compare the 0th element and sort.